# Wireshark shows duplicate IP address detected

Tags: mac-address, arp, ip-address

Wireshark shows that an IP address belongs to two different MAC addresses:

wireshark

I spoofed ARP, and I use VMware.

How can I fix this? How is it possible that one IP address can belong to two different MAC addresses? Is it related to my use of VMware? Is something wrong in my ARP spoofing? How is that possible?

Is it normal when I open arp -a on the victim machine and it says that one IP address has two different MAC addresses?

I did arp spoofing on my router and another computer. My other computer is the victim. When I open cmd on the victim computer, and I run arp -a it says:

[image: Screenshot of arp -a result]

How is this possible? It happened after the ARP spoof.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RonMaupin How to fix this? how it can be possible that one ip address can be in double macaddress ? 

its related to this im on vmware ? maybe something wrong in my arospoof ? but how it can be possible ?!

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do? It seems you're spoofing the 192.168.1.20 address, so it's normal that both (the real device, and the spoofing device) andswer the arp request.

Comment: @mulaz Is it normal when i open arp -a on the victim machine and its said that one ip address have two mac address ?

Comment: You need to edit your question to be specific: state what you think is wrong, what you have done to try to correct the problem, and ask a specific question.

Comment: @mulaz look on this - http://postimg.org/image/676ahby2x/

Comment: @RonMaupin Look. I did arp spoofing on my router and my another computer. 
my another computer is the victim. 
when i open cmd on the computer victim and run arp -a 
it said 
http://postimg.org/image/676ahby2x/

how it can be possible ? *its after the arp spoof*

Comment: You need to edit your question, which isn't a question. The Help Center can guide you on how to ask a proper question. Your question needs to be clear and specific, and you need to edit it to fix it.

Comment: @RonMaupin But it said my English is not correct. can you please help me edit my question ?

Comment: @Antonio, your question is very unclear and is lacking in detail. Start by providing the IP address in use by your hosts (call them "Host A" and "Host B" or something to reference elsewhere in the post for clarity) and router. Add detail about which host is doing the ARP spoofing and exactly what/how it is spoofing. Let us know what you are expecting to happen, what is happening and why this doesn't match up. Clarify your information, for instance in your post you mention one IP address with two different MAC addresses, but your screenshot shows one MAC address with multiple IP addresses.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

ARP spoofing is just the thing that is doing the multiple MAC's for one IP. :)
So if you want to avoid duplicate adresses... stop ARP spoofing (poisoning) your network.

If you want to understand this, read the following page:

http://www.arppoisoning.com/how-does-arp-poisoning-work/

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of thing that happens when you break a network by hacking it, and it is perfectly normal behavior. You can also get this result if you assign the same IP address to two different hosts, which is basically what you did when you spoofed ARP.

This is an attack on the network; bad guys do this sort of thing to disrupt a network. Doing this sort of thing on a network belonging to someone else can get you in a lot of trouble. It's OK to do this on your own network if you want to see what happens, and you saw the results (not good).